# Mysql SELECT query and performance

Tags: mysql, django, performance, django-queryset, database-performance

I was wondering if there is a performance gain between a `SELECT` query with a not very specific WHERE clause and another `SELECT` query with a more specific `WHERE` clause.

For instance is the query:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE first_name='Georges';
```

slower than this one:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE first_name='Georges' AND nickname='Gigi';
```

In other words is there a time factor that is link to the precision of the `WHERE` clause ?

I'm not sure to be very understandable and even if my question takes into account all the components that are involved in database query (MYSQL in my case)

My question is related to the Django framework because I would like to cache an evaluated queryset, and on a next request, take back this cached-evaluated queryset, filter it more, and evaluate it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no hard and fast rule about this.

There can be either an increase or decrease in performance by adding more conditions to the `WHERE` clause, as it depends on, among other things, the:

- indexing
- schema
- data quantity
- data cardinality
- statistics
- intelligence of the query engine

You need to test with your data set and determine what will perform the best.

Answer (score 1):

MySql server must compare all columns in your `WHERE` clause (if all joined by `AND` ).

So if you don't have any index on column `nickname` second query will by slightly slower.

Here you can read how column indexes works (with examples similar to your question): http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html

Answer (score 1):

I think is difficult to answer this question, too many aspects (e.g.: indexes) are involved. I would say that the first query is **faster** than the first one, but I can't say for sure.

If this is crucial for you, why don't you run a simulation (e.g.: run 1'000'000 of queries) and check the time?

Comment: I've a big ammount of entries in a database and it is most likely that similar requests are performed, refined through different requests. Thanks anyway I'll try to find what's best through a simulation for my case. Which would you say is faster than the other one ? 1st faster than the 2nd or the opposite ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be slower. It will all depend on indexes you have and data distribution. 
Check the link [Understanding the Query Execution Plan](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/execution-plan-information.html)

for information on how to know what MySQL is going to do when executing your query.

Comment: Also check these links how to optimize MySQL: http://juixe.com/techknow/index.php/2007/01/29/mysql-optimization-tutorial/ and http://www.codeforest.net/8-great-mysql-performance-tips